# Pull random data from data.json and shuffle it

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mustache

I have a json data sheet with a bunch of objects which I am displaying on my page

```
{ "objects": [ ... ] }
```

templating:

```
$(function () {
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    var template = $('#objectstpl').html(),
        html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
    $('.thumb-area').html(html);
  }); //get data
}); //function
```

however what I would like to do is pull only a limited amount of these objects into my data variable, and then display them in a random manner. In theory it sound easy - take the data, put parts of it into a variable and shuffle.

I tried doing something like this to shuffle my dataset:

```
var randomizeEntries = data[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)];
```

But it does not save any data into the variable and I cannot understand why. Would appreciate any tips.

Comment: If data looks like: `{"objects": [ ... ]}`, shouldn't you use: `data.objects[Math.floor...]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a JSON object data .You need to convert it to array before getting the random objects out like -

```
var arr = [];

for(var i in object){
  arr.push(object[i]);
}

var randomizeEntries = arr[Math.floor( Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length))];
```

Comment: you are absolutely right, however how would I feed the new array to Mustache?

Comment: ok ,so may be we can have the randomizeEntries to be an abject insted of array like this -`var randomizeEntries = {};
 randomizeEntries.someThing  = arr[Math.floor( Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length))];`